# How do I redirect domain to subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

.htaccess is a bit new to me!

I have a current site located at www.domain.com and I'm building a new site at new.domain.com.

When the new site is finished, I want to re-direct all traffic to the new subdomain.

Also, I want to resolve url canonicalization at the same time.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks
Mark

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the sub-domain administration tool of your ISP?

Answer (score 8):

There are several different solutions. The best one, both from SEO and User perspective, is the one-to-one 301 redirect. It preserves your link juice and at the same time redirects the client to the exact location on the new website.

If you have mod_alias enabled, I would suggest a simple

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ / http://new.domain.com/$1
```

The result instruction can be accomplished with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second one is the best choice if you need to chain multiple conditions and filters. For example, if you need to redirect only certain hosts or clients depending on User Agent header.

Remember: mod_redirect takes precedence over mod_alias.

Comment: thanks, the redirect statement looks like the one! I also want to also resolve any canonicalizaton issues; would that go bfore or after the ReDirectMatch statement? Thanks, Mark

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean with "resolve any canonicalizaton issues"?

Comment: At the moment I don't have anything in htaccess to help resolve www & non www incoming requests to just one option; I believe Google prefers this? I was wondering what instruction I would use and whether it would come before or after the ReDirectMach instruction?

Comment: This should really be done with just plain `Redirect`, as that regex pattern is is exactly what `Redirect` performs.  For  example, `Redirect 301 / http://new.domain.com/`

Answer (score 6):

put this in the old site htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/
```

this is a good link to learn about this :

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this just did the trick in my case. Perfect! Now all the links shown by Google redirect from the top domain to the same link at the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use this code so you don't have to worry about the "www" part of the URL address.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mysite.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not point the old domain to the new site, once it is finished? I think it should be no problem to point to domains on the same directory.

Comment: Maybe he wants to be able to redirect users coming from existing links to the new site, but at the same time tell all search engines that the old domain will be abandoned shortly. Basically a grace period in between everyone can slowly clear there databases.

Comment: Hi,

that's basically it, except I want to keep www.domain.com as the adverised url for the site.

Answer (score -1):

What about this solution:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule is overkill when all you need is a plain old redirection

Comment: Aren't you loosing all the path/file/parameter info, if you are just using a trivial redirect?

Comment: I agree, overkill. mod_rewrite is often presented for simple redirects, most of which could be done via mod_alias.  This is my dimple rule of thumb: If something *can* be done with `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`, don't use `Rewrite...`.