# DNS Redirect domain to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I am looking for a way to redirect a domain to its subdomain via DNS a / cname records.

Is it possible to have these examples done totally in DNS, I know it can be easily done with .htaccess and PHP.

```
website.com => blog.website.com
website.com/hello => blog.website.com/hello
www.website.com => blog.website.com
www.website.com/hello => blog.website.com/hello
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a CNAME in DNS but this won't update the address that appears in the browser.

Comment: Short answer is no, look into mod-rewrite via htaccess

Comment: how would you do www.website.com/hello => blog.website.com/hello via cname?

Comment: lol, I was unaware of its limitations, I understand now.

Comment: The third line in your example above should be possible via a CNAME record. (Such a CNAME record might also take care of the fourth example, too.) As for the first line in your example, see: https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS is only for associating domain names with an IP address. You cannot do a *redirection* with it.

You will have to handle the redirection on the web server side. You just need to throw an HTTP `301 Permanently moved` to let your visitors know the new address whether with an `.htaccess`  file if you are using apache, or a simple PHP script with an `header()` function.

Comment: Any change to have a mod rewrite example on hand?

Comment: Yes, http://code.pobourgeois.com/V

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031341/how-do-i-redirect-domain-to-subdomain-using-htaccess

Comment: aww beat me to it. THANKS A BUNCH!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CNAME in DNS to point another name to the same address as a different name, making it easier to change the IP of both.  I.E. if your mail www and ftp are all on the same IP you can setup one and point the other two at the first so if the IP changes only one needs to change.

However, this is not redirection.  If you use either or both in your web pages, the domain name will not change as you navigate.  That must be accomplished through some other means.  Basically you need to do as mentioned above with a 301 Permanently Moved or 302 Temporarily Moved.  This can be accomplished in a large number of ways either with the web server or with code.

If you are using Apache, look at mod_rewrite which is typically enabled by default.  This can either go into your config or your .htaccess as you mentioned.  If you are using another web server consult its documentation.

By code you can emit a Location header to effect the redirect.  Most languages have libraries that will assist you in this process.

Answer (score 0):

DNS (well, the A/CNAME records, at least) just tells a system "the corresponding IP address for this series of characters is 123.456.789.000". The rest is up to the server at that IP.

Comment: AFAICT, you're correct about A records, but not about CNAME records.