# Can I use a subdomain to point / redirect to a XML feed?

Tags: xml, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, rss

Using `feed.myblog.com` as a redirect to `myblog.com/feed.xml` works for all the RSS services like FeedPress, Feedburner, etc. They do it via CNAME.

Can I mimic this clean look? I tried some stuff in my Apache server's `.htaccess` and tried to set up a redirect on Namecheap, but had no luck.

So, is it possible and if yes, how can I achieve this?

Matter of fact, I know how to point the xml file to the subdomain (see ["php - DNS Redirect domain to subdomain - Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896877/dns-redirect-domain-to-subdomain?rq=1)), but obviously when I do this there will be no feed, just an empty domain.

I can't wrap my head around it what I have to do to make it work.

---

**Update 2:**

My basically empty `.htaccess` (from myblog.com). I removed the the redirect of `feed.xml` to `feed.myblog.com`, because - like stated above - it makes no sense since the target (feed.myblog.com) is empty.

```
# BEGIN Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# END Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
# BEGIN REDIRECTS
Redirect /start http://private.blog.tld/
Redirect /itunes https://itunes.apple.com/de/podcast/our-podcast/id123456789/
Redirect /end https://myblog.com/info
# END REDIRECTS
# SET DEFAULTS
ErrorDocument 404 /dir/404/
ErrorDocument 403 /dir/403/
```

---

**Thoughts:**

- I could use a CNAME (feed.myblog.com ==> myblog.com), but then there is no way to make `feed.myblog.com` point to `myblog.com/feed.xml` without messing up the main sites home page (myblog.com/index.html).
- I could "copy" the whole site to "feed.myblog.com" and set a redirect from `/` to `feed.xml`.

Both sound strange and overcomplicated.

I'll a try 301 redirect on `feed.myblog.com/.htaccess` now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://myblog.com/feed.xml$1 [R=301,L]
```

Fingers crossed that it works across all Podcast/RSS clients.

Comment: can you show what you have done? update your post to add your .htaccess

Comment: @Ben I added my `.htaccess` and provided some more context and thoughts.

Comment: any use cases or rules you want to apply? says `{subdomain}.myblog.com` redirect to `myblog.com/{subdomain}.xml`? otherwise you only need a simple rewriterule to make a redirect