# How to redirect from domain to subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My site is www.mysite.com and I need to redirect any request to us.mysite.com.

So:

```
 www.mysite.com ----> us.mysite.com
 www.mysite.com/hello.php ----> us.mysite.com/hello.php
 // etc
```

I tryed this but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://us.mysite.com$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I think a simple redirect permanent / http: // us.mysite.com could do it!

Comment: Remove spaces around // of course (it became a link without them)

Comment: Http:space here//space here in comment above! :)

Comment: ah but how can I do this with htaccess ?

Comment: Sorry, missed that tag... No knowledge in htaccess I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `RewriteCond` is only matching domains that start and end with `mysite.com`. This does not include `www.mysite.com`.

The following will 301 redirect anything NOT at `us.mysite.com` to `us.mysite.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^us.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://us.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different solutions. The best one, both from SEO and User perspective, is the one-to-one 301 redirect. It preserves your link juice and at the same time redirects the client to the exact location on the new website.

If you have mod_alias enabled, I would suggest a simple

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ / http://new.domain.com/$1
The result instruction can be accomplished with

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
The second one is the best choice if you need to chain multiple conditions and filters. For example, if you need to redirect only certain hosts or clients depending on User Agent header.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031341/how-do-i-redirect-domain-to-subdomain-using-htaccess).