# Mapping sub domain to custom domain in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want to point sub domain to custom domain.

e.g. I got the subdomain "`company.xyz.com`", now i already have a domain abc.com want to map my "`abc.com`" domain to the "`company.xyz.com`", so how we can achieve this?

Our application is written in `Core Php.`

Is there any script in php or can be achievable using php?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031341/how-do-i-redirect-domain-to-subdomain-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in the .htaccess file of abc.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://company.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```